# how to find component in stenciljs shadow dom using jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer, shadow-dom, stenciljs

In Stencil e2e tests, I can find components using the ["piercing" selector >>>](https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing) only when selecting from an element that doesn't have a shadow DOM:

for example

```
// defined as vars because they are reused in a sequence of tests  
var page: E2EPage,
    root: E2EElement,
    home: E2EElement,
    recipe: E2EElement,
    master: E2EElement

it('renders', async () => {
    page = await newE2EPage()
    await page.setContent('<app-root/>')

    root = await page.find('app-root')
    expect(root).toHaveClass('hydrated')

    home = await root.find('app-home')
    expect(home).not.toBeNull()

    recipe = await home.find('wizard-layout > screen-recipe >>> recipe-manager')
    expect(recipe).not.toBeNull()

    master = await home.find('wizard-layout > screen-recipe >>> recipe-manager >>> master-detail')
    expect(master).not.toBeNull()

  })
```

works (= all the tests pass)

However I'd like to obtain the master from the recipe with a shorter selector string. I tried all this, they all failed ( master is Null or undefined) :

```
master = await recipe.find(':host: >>> master-detail')
master = await recipe.find(':scope >>> master-detail')
master = await recipe.find('>>> master-detail')
```

how can jest/puppeteer find a component in the shadow DOM of a given stencil component ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use CSS selectors like you have to select shadowed elements.

You'd need to select them one by one, like this :

// psudo-code

```
recipeElement
.shadowRoot
.querySelctor('myElement')
```

This gets worse when `myElement` itself has a shadow root and you want to drill even further, then you end up with things like below :

```
recipeElement
.shadowRoot
.querySelctor('myElement')
.shadowRoot
.querySelector('deepedElement')
```